# Testing google account picker on emulator older than 4.2.2 (API level 17)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-account

My app uses google account picker. I am trying to test my app on emulator. The account picker seems to work okay on emulator with a virtual device of target Google APIs API Level 17. But anything older than that fails with below error when the account picker code is invoked.

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT (has extras) }
```

Is there a way test with Google Account picker on emulator with target older than 4.2.2? Because I would like to test how my app works on API 11+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478471/activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently going through the details of the same, and i found what is obviously stated in the [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), where it was unfortunately and clearly stated that it only works in two cases :

1. A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
2. The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

I hope they give support for other devices as well.